# Console command:The file was found but the class was not in it,the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

first off, what I'm trying to do is learn to create own console commands using the documentation
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

I want to replicate exactly what is being done on the documentation

This is what I've got so far

```
<?
// src/Gabriel/LiveLoginBundle/Command/GreetCommand.php
namespace Gabriel\LiveLoginBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class GreetCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('demo:greet')
        ->setDescription('Greet someone')
        ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Who do you want to greet?')
        ->addOption('yell', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'If set, the task will yell in uppercase letters');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $name = $input->getArgument('name');

        if ($name)
        {
            $text = 'Hello '.$name;
        }
        else
        {
            $text = 'Hello';
        }

        if ($input->getOption('yell'))
        {
            $text = strtoupper($text);
        }

        $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

but for some reason it throws this error, it can't seem to find the class

> The file was found but the class was not in it,the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

PS: already tried deleting the cache

Comment: Try with a correct <?php  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your PHP configuration (php.ini) doesn't allow you to use the short opening tags

```
<? ?>
<?= ?>
```

So you have to add the following instruction in your php.ini

```
short_open_tag=On
```

The best idea would be to replace your short tag `<?` by the full one `<?php` everywhere